# How could I pack my Python code to run it on different machines/os?

Tags: java, python

I'm used to use Java to create little programas (a single jar file) that run on different machines with different os even if they don't have Java installed. What I do to achieve this is to place a copy of the jre in a folder along with my jar file and then call the java executable from the jre to run the jar file.

```
\jre\bin\java -jar .\my_jar_file.jar
```

This way I can run my code on Windows or Linux without having to install Java.

Is there a way to achieve this using python?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker for this goal.
You can containerize your application. And run on any OS that supports docker.
https://runnable.com/docker/python/dockerize-your-python-application

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I know that the way I'm doing this is not the best approach, but there are some reasons for that.
For example one of the machines that I mention is a Linux server were I cannot install anything even docker.